# Signal integrity at 40 MHz with parallel signals

Tags: pcb-design, signal-integrity

I have to design a board with an 8 bit parallel port that carries 40 MHz signals. It is not possible to wire them very short and in parallel (I am sure the wires will be about 7 cm long), so I have to wire them separately in pairs of 2 or 3 wires together because my microcontroller doesn't have all the port pins together (TQFP44 package).

Is any signal integrity considerations at this frequency ? I use Altium and can make trace length equal but this wires are not alone and maybe can affect other wires such as UART, TIMER inputs, etc. Moreover signals are not differential so I don't know what problems can it cause.

**EDIT:**

It is my microcontroller:
[image]

I need to use the 8-bit low side or 8-bit high side of PORTB (16 bits) or PORTC (16 bits) to connect it to an 8-bit buffer. As you can see pins are not consecutive so I will have to wire the traces whit more length (I have been say that at 40MHz length is not a problem yet) but I don't know how it can affect to other traces and how can I prevent high frequency problems like EMI.

Comment: I can (and must because is the same port) wire 2 or 3 in parallel will that cause any problem ? Will this 40 MHz wires affect other wires ? If yes, is any way to prevent that ?

Comment: You appear to be somewhat over your head there.  A dsPIC's top speed is what, 120 MHz? That gives 30 MFlops or at most 15 MHz out of a single pin being repeatedly toggled on/off. I guess the most you could take out of one in a parallel 8 bit bus would be in the 500 kHz ballpark and that's doing nothing else.

Comment: It is not a pure DSP, it is a dsPIC whit a maximum speed of 40 MIPS and I am not toggling a pin, I am reading a high speed signal through a buffer that's because I need to take some considerations to design my PCB :)

Comment: What is on the other end of the signal, and how are you doing clocking for this? Is there a data strobe line or are you relying on clock synchronisation? Also, could you correct "whit" to "with" everywhere please?

Comment: @Kristoffon - these dsPICs have a parallel master port (PMP) and DMA, so you can clock data in/out at a fair speed and do plenty of other stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me start by saying that 7 cm is not a long distance to go for 40 MHz signals.  I've ran double that frequently and didn't even break a sweat.  Below is a list of issues that you need to consider when doing this:

Trace length:  As I just said, 7 cm is not far.  But look at your timing budget.  If your budget is tight you might have to do something called "matched trace lengths", where every signal of your bus has the same length.  Odds are that at 40 MHz you don't need this, but it is worth looking into.

Parallel traces:  Try to keep some space between signals on this bus.  This is super important for clock and control signals, and less important for data.  A normal PCB might have 0.008 inches (0.2 mm) between traces, and you might consider doubling or tippling that.  It is OK for them to be close for short distances, but the longer the traces the farther apart they should be.

Power/Ground Planes:  Yes, have them.  This is important.  Run your traces on a layer that is adjacent to the power or ground plane.  I am skipping over a LOT of details here that pertain to high-speed digital design.  This is an area for you to learn more of in the future.  If you can't have a power/gnd plane then your problem has gotten 10 times harder.  Run a ground trace next to each signal trace and hope for the best!

Termination:  Yes, use them!  If the signals are going from one chip to another (and not connecting to more chips) then using source termination is the easiest.  Normally that would be a 33 to 50 ohm resistor in series and located at the driver of the signal.

Decoupling caps:  Make sure that all chips are properly decoupled.  Then add decoupling caps near places where signals move through a via (no more than 1 cap every 3 square cm).  Again, I am skipping details but at 40 MHz you don't need to worry that much.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am at first year of electronic engineering and don't know that much we haven't seen anything yet I have learned most things by myself. I will use 2 layer board only design is not that complicated. One layer should be whit power traces (3.3V, 5V, GND) and the other layer for signal traces ? I didn't know about termination resistors, that is interesting :) Is any book from a can learn that kind of things ? :)

Comment: @Andres You don't want a 2 layer PCB with a plane on one layer and signals on the other.  It makes for an unbalanced PCB that is prone to warping.  Also, the two layers are too far apart from each other to be useful.  You'll have to put GND traces between your bus signals.  A good book is "High Speed Digital Design:  A Handbook of Black Magic" (http://www.amazon.com/High-Speed-Digital-Design-Handbook/dp/0133957241/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1343656364&sr=8-1&keywords=high+speed+handbook+black+magic)  It is expensive but you will save lots of time and money in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) What distance should I have between GND traces and my high speed traces ?

Comment: @Andres As close as is reasonable given the PCB shop.  An "average" PCB might have 0.008 inch traces with 0.008 inch spaces between traces.  That would be a good target for you.  Less is better, but not required.

Answer (score -5):

The spacing between lines doesn't matter in the slightest. The spacing to ground is important. Use a complete ground plane on your pcb. If connecting to a cable use one ground per signal above 5 MHz. Track lengths only matter if you are running at ten times this speed or if your timing margins are poor. I assume this is point to point connection with series terminations at the transmit end ?

Comment: The connection goes from an 8 bit high speed buffer which read external signals (there is a cable there) to a 8 bit port in a DSP microcontroller. The ground plane or trace have to be very close to the 40 MHz traces ? Is there any formula to calculate it ? I don't know what series terminations are if you could explain me.

Comment: -1 Because this answer is full of generalizations and rules of thumb that are simply not true.  Spacing between signals does matter.  MHz of signal doesn't change when you need a GND/signal in a cable.  Track lengths do matter at less than 50 MHz.  The only thing that's accurate here is track lengths become even more important when timing margins are slim.

Comment: Thank you :) So I will equalize net lenghts. Is there any other consideration I have to take into account ? Distance between traces ? Distance between my high speed traces and GND ? :)

Comment: Tony Stewart? Is that you?

Comment: @FakeName Sounds like him.

Comment: I don't think it's Tony; he'd be telling us about how he used matched length coax for a 40 MHz bus in the 1980's for a military computer.

Comment: @ThePhoton - OTOH, there's the 5 downvotes :-)